# Counting integers from $1$ to $n$ with an odd number of divisors in {1,2,3,...,k}

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

**Question**

Given $n,k$ find the number of integers between $1$ and $n$ that have odd number of divisors in {1,2,3,...,k}

**Example**

If $n=10$ and $k=3$, the numbers $1(1),5(1),6(1,2,3),7(1)$ have odd number of divisors each of which is less than or equal to $3$.
For instance 8 has 1,2 as its divisors so it's not qualified to be in the solution set

Comment: Are you searching for an asymptotic estimate?

Comment: I doubt there's any useful exact formula for this function of two variables. What is it that you really need to know?

Comment: most efficient way of solving this problem

Comment: I think theres no closed form only number. Of divisors is given by $(a+1)(b+1)..$ where $a,b..$ are primes implying a has to be even for odd divisors that means only numbers with divisor only as $2$ is $2,4,8,$ that continues till k

Comment: The most efficient way may be to divide each number from 1 to $n$ by each number from 2 to $k$ and count how many have an odd number of divisors. Or, it might be to factor every number from 1 to $n$ and produce all the factors of each number from 1 to $n$ and then for each see how many of those factors are between 1 and $k$. Come on, give us some information. Why do you need an efficient way to solve this problem? What range of values of the pair $(n,k)$ do you envision? Is it just a one-off, or do you need to calculate millions of these? Don't keep secrets – help us help you.

Comment: Are you still here, Akhil?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.